# AWS S3 presigned URL invalid AWS Access Key Id

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I am working on image upload in my application. I use presigned POST URLs to upload a file to my S3 bucket. The function responsible for creating an URL looks as follows

```js
  public createUrl(filename: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.s3.createPresignedPost(
        {
          Bucket: "{{bucket-name}}",
          Fields: {
            key: filename,
          },
          Conditions: [
            ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576],
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
          ],
          Expires: 120,
        },
        (error, data) => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          else resolve(data);
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

where the s3 object is created as follows

```js
import { S3 } from "aws-sdk";

export const s3 = new S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});
```

When I test everything using `sls offline` command all seems to work fine, I get the following response

```js
{
    "url": "https://s3.{{region}}.amazonaws.com/{{bucket-name}}",
    "fields": {
        "key": "{{filename}}.png",
        "bucket": "{{bucket-name}}",
        "X-Amz-Algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
        "X-Amz-Credential": "AKIA{{key}}/20220619/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request",
        "X-Amz-Date": "20220619T131035Z",
        "Policy": "{{policy-token}}",
        "X-Amz-Signature": "{{signature}}"
    }
}
```

I can then make a request using all these values to upload an image to my bucket and the image is indeed uploaded. But whenever I deploy all of it using `sls deploy`, the data generated by the function looks completely fine, then when I invoke the s3 presigned url I get the following response

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIA{{key}}</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId>{{id}}</RequestId>
    <HostId>{{host-id}}</HostId>
</Error>
```

What is worth mentioning is the fact that when I use `sls offline` the key I get starts with `AKIA...` but when I invoke a deployed version I get `ASIA...`. Also the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environment variable is set properly because I also use DynamoDB client and it works fine, where I use the very same variable .

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out that the problem was completely on my side. I don't know why but when I changed the lines

```js
export const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});
```

and instead of using environment variables, I put directly these values as strings, everything magically started to work. I have no idea why this is like that because I literally use these environment variables when setting up my DynamoDB client which works completely fine. Now instead of getting `ASIA...` keys I get `AKIA...` keys which work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`ASIA...` vs `AKIA...` suggests you're using STS (temporary credentials generated with assumed role). This is typical in Lambda, since you don't use access keys, but it rather assumes a role through its IAM execution role. This means that for each call it generates temporary credentials with short expiry and uses them to execute whatever it needs (in this case, pre-signing a URL).

When actually downloading/uploading from the client-side, you need to send 'X-Amz-Security-Token' in the body with the value you get when pre-signing. Unfortunately this is not clearly documented by AWS.

In NodeJS this would be:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const credentials = s3.config.credentials;
const sessionToken = credentials.sessionToken;
```

In PHP it was

```
$credentials = $s3client->getCredentials()->wait();
$sessionToken = $credentials->getSecurityToken();
```

And when uploading/downloading the file, you would send this as Body:

```
"acl": presignUploadData.acl, // for upload
"key": presignUploadData.key, // the key you presigned for download/upload
"X-Amz-Credential": presignUploadData.XAmzCredential,
"X-Amz-Algorithm": presignUploadData.XAmzAlgorithm,
"X-Amz-Date": presignUploadData.XAmzDate,
"Policy": presignUploadData.Policy,
"X-Amz-Signature": presignUploadData.XAmzSignature,
"X-Amz-Security-Token": presignUploadData.XAmzSecurityToken,
```